# Express with ParseServer - Failed to connect to <ip> port 1337, connection timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform, centos7

I configured parse server on my custom server on centos 7. Its working fine when running curl command from this server command prompt for testing its working fine, but when try to call it from my local system terminal using curl then its giving connection timeout.
I also try this with my php sdk code.

Here is parse server index.js file :---

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',    
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',    
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',    
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!    
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://<ip addr>:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed    
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Employee"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions, this database collections directly used at client end

  }
});

// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});


// Web endpoints
//app.get('/', homeController.index);
//app.get('/about', aboutController.index);


var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

My Php code :-

```
<?php

require 'autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
//use Parse\ParseACL;
//use Parse\ParsePush;
//use Parse\ParseUser;
//use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
//use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
//use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;

try {
    ParseClient::initialize("myAppId", "", "", true);
    // Users of Parse Server will need to point ParseClient at their remote URL and Mount Point:
    ParseClient::setServerURL('http://<ip address>:1337', 'parse');

//Save data start
    $gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");

    $gameScore->set("score", 1337);
    $gameScore->set("playerName", "zakir");
    $gameScore->set("cheatMode", false);


    $gameScore->save();
    echo 'New object created with objectId: ' . $gameScore->getObjectId();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
    // error is a ParseException object with an error code and message.
    echo 'Failed to create new object, with error message: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

When run following url in browser this also gives connection timeout:-
http://:1337/test

Please help me, what can I do to access it from my client side sdk code?

Comment: "`http://<ip addr>:1337/parse`"

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the server from a prompt on your server directly but not from your local terminal, the problem are either some firewall issues (could be a case when using centos) or the parse process not listening on the correct interface.

Please check which ip address is used when your httpServer is bound. I assume it isn't bound on the correct interface. To check which services are listening on which interface, try the following:

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN
```

If you see something like `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` there for your port number `1337`, the server must be started with a correct IP to bind to. You can pass this as additional parameter like this:

```
httpServer.listen(port, ip, function() { /* ... */ });
```

Please note that you probably also have to adapt the `serverURL` property of your parse configuration to match the correct address. [See here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server--express).